# Store an array in a cookie

Tags: javascript

I want to store an array in a cookie in order to get it later. I don't know why but the output is not an array. I tried to stringify it and parse it but it doesn't change anything.

```
  var arr = '["Template 43","normal"]'
  console.log(arr) // => ["Template 43","normal"]
  value = JSON.stringify(arr)
  console.log(value) // => "[\"Template 43\",\"normal\"]"
  setCookie_text('meta_template', value)
  cookie = getCookie('meta_template') 
  h = JSON.parse(cookie);
  console.log(h) // => ["Template 43","normal"]
  console.log(h[0]) // => [
```

Comment: You're "double-stringifying" the array. Just make a normal array, don't try to make it a string at the start: `var arr = ["Template 43","normal"];`

Comment: Why are you stringify a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `arr` as a `string`, not `array`!

Try this, this should work:

```
var arr = ["Template 43", "normal"];
console.log(arr); 
var value = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(value); 
setCookie_text('meta_template', value);
var cookie = getCookie('meta_template');
var h = JSON.parse(cookie);
console.log(h); 
console.log(h[0]);
```

Comment: Ok yes, this is working that way but I in order to simplify the question I removed the part where "arr" is from an input value

Comment: @Mathieu If it's a string then why are you trying to stringify it again? Just save the input value as is.

Comment: Ok, I've just understood that... Thank you